# Uudeview cli in Windows – alternative?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm using uudeview cli Windows port for extarcting attachments from EML files in bath mode. 
But current software version (https://github.com/maiken2051/uudeview) has problem: it saves file names in original EML file encoding. If it's not CP866, file name gets broken.
Are there alternatives to this software?

Answer (score 1):

Well, no help came, so I'm trying to do it myself. First, I contacted uudeview for Windows developer with this bug. Second, I forked similiar project https://github.com/erikvdv1/eml-attachments .